# Rollback not working in spring-boot application

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, transactions

In my spring-boot application I have problem with rollback in transaction method. For test purpose I have this example:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void insertPersonSaveLog() {
    refService.insertPerson(); 
    String a = null;
    a.getBytes();
    auditService.editRequest();
}
```

in log I can see that rollback should be perform but person is still saved in my db. Maybe I am missing some annotation. This is Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class).run(args);
}
```

}

and stacktrace:

```
149254 DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager  - Initiating transaction commit
149254 DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager  - Creating new transaction with name [..]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',-java.lang.Exception
149254 DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager  - Participating in existing transaction
149258 DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL query
149258 DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement
149258 DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
149258 DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection
149260 DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement
149262 DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
149262 DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager  - Initiating transaction rollback
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.my.service.InserPersonService.insertPersonSaveLog(InserPersonService.java:77)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
```

DbConfig:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.ref")
@Primary
public DataSource refDataSource() {
    return new DataSource();
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate refJdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(refDataSource());
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.log")
public DataSource logDataSource() {
    return new DataSource();
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate logJdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(logDataSource());
}
```

and application.properties:

```
datasource.ref.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@something:1521:ora11g
datasource.ref.username=...
datasource.ref.password=...
datasource.ref.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

datasource.log.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@something:1521:ora11g
datasource.log.username=...
datasource.log.password=...
datasource.log.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: I am using oracle db.

Comment: Are you using Spring Data Repos?

Comment: added db config. DataSource is from tomcat-jbbc with spring jdbcTemplate